# selecting root element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to be able to select the root element from a **fragment** without knowing the node types, class, id or hierachy.

```
<div id="0">
    <div id="0a">
        <div id="a01"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="0b">
    </div>
    <div id="0c">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to do something like $(':root') and have 0 selected in the example above.

Better still I would prefer `$(':level(0)')` which would mean the same as above, `$(':level(1)')` would select 0a, 0b and 0c and `$(':level(1)>div')` would select a01.

Any ideas on how to do it neatly?

Comment: are there any defining properties that let you know what is the 'root' element in your case? ie, what is stopping you from traversing to what element <div id="0"> is contained in?

Comment: Define "root element" in your example.

Comment: As in the outermost element, in this case `<div id="0">`

Comment: the outermost element of *what*?

If you are holding this tree as dom element foo, then you want $(foo).  It's that simple.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a clear conception of what you're trying to select; if you do then you're not communicating it effectively. When you say "I need a way to do `:root`", what is your starting point that you're trying to select from?  Also, the markup in your comment is hard to read. It's not even valid - you're missing a close tag somewhere. I'd recommend editing it into your original question.

Comment: BTW your argu... your id attributes are invalid: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: I believe either your question should be rephrased or you should reconsider what answer you have selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst this question was answered a while ago perfectly correctly - I was just trying to attempt this myself and wasn't too keen on using a selector like `*:not(* *)` -- mainly because of the probable overheads. I don't know if this is a recent addition to jQuery's ability *(i'm using 1.8)* but you can use:

```
$(':eq(0)');
```

This will select the first found non-textnode element, so unless the dom you are traversing is illegal in it's formation, you should always get the root element. It is also highly optimal because jQuery should know to stop after the first element found.

So here's a little something for all of those WSOD fans out there:

```
$(':eq(0)').remove();
```

Oh and just in case it isn't obvious that the above code snippets were just illustrating the selector, and you find yourself working with a partial fragment (rather than the full document), then you should use this selector with jQuery's filter method:

```
$(fragment).filter(':eq(0)');
```

However, when working with fragments you can just do the following:

```
$(fragment).get(0);
```

Although bear in mind that `.get(0)` can select text/comment nodes if they are the first item in your document, whereas the filter approach will always find the first actual element.

Comment: I changed to this answer, not because there was anything wrong with the old accepted answer by @Deeksy just that this is neater and more semantically clear

Comment: This question-answer couple is kinda confusing. The question suggests that the root element is NOT a document root (a div-element instead of html-element), yet the selected answer would ALWAYS return document.documentElement. Either the answer is missing a context parameter or the question should make it clear that the desired element is 1) within a document & 2) a document root element. If this is the correct answer then the question should be renamed to "How to reference a document root element?"

Comment: In other words, if the fragment was not inserted into a document your answer would still return root element of the document, i.e. it would not return the div with "0" id.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so what you need to do is the following (presuming that you are using the sample you've got), if you want to find the top level node using jquery is the following:

```
 $('*:not(* *)');
```

What you are literally asking for here is for all nodes that are not children of other nodes.  The problem is that for a html document, this will always give you only the html element, which isn't particularly useful.  So, if you want to find the top level element within the body of a html document, you'd use something a lot simpler:

```
 $('body > *');
```

if you then wanted the second level, you'd just go

```
 $('body > * > *');
```

But, presuming you have some sort of arbitrary document structure (like the foo one you mention), what you can do is use the first example to find the first level:

```
 $('*:not(* *)');
```

and then for the second level

```
 $('*:not(* *)').find('> *');
```

and for the third level

```
 $('*:not(* *)').find('> * > *');
```

and so on and so forth.  If you're looking for a root div element (presuming that your sample is like the question), you can do this:

```
 $('div:not(div div)');
```

and so on, replacing * with div.  Not really sure why you'd want to do this, but it will work.  The problem is the question doesn't really provide enough context for us to give you a better alternative.

Comment: For the particular foo example mentioned in the comments, it's  $('foo:not(foo foo)');

Comment: $('*:not(* *)'); 

Was exactly what I was after, and came close myself not didnt quite get it right. The examples using BODY were all things I couldnt do as I had no idea what was contained within the tree (it could be *any* snippet including arbitary XML) :)

Comment: Also thank you for understanding the question, that is that I wanted a jQuery selector and not a piece of JS code (I know how easy this can be done in JS)

Answer (score 2):

I'm more of a Prototype guy, but I think you could get all the nodes then get the first node in the array:

```
$('*')[0]
```

Then get the child items of that (for 0a, 0b and 0c)

```
$('*')[0].children()
```

Comment: so far this looks like the best solution, will have to have a think

Answer (score 2):

If you've got your elements as a jQuery fragment like:

```
var myElements = $('<div id="0">
<div id="0a">
    <div id="a01"></div>
</div>
<div id="0b">
</div>
<div id="0c">
</div>
</div>');
```

then you can find the first element by:

```
myElements.filter(":first")
```

The filter function looks from the root element of the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not needed...

```
var root = document.firstChild;
```

Comment: promissing idea, although I may be doing this from a current jQuery selection, so I really need a way of doing it from jQuery

Comment: @Boldewyn, this was not a general JavaScript query, this was specifically a question about jQuery selectors. Why are you wasting your time writing rude comments when you don't even understand the question?

Comment: RE: first comment - `var root = $(document.firstChild);`

Comment: Jquery allows elements and node lists to be passed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but assuming by root you mean the point at which the parent is a different tag to the child then the following should work.

```
function GetRoot(element) {
    while(element.parent().attr("tagName") == element.attr("tagName")) {
        element = element.parent();
    }

    return element;
}
```

This basically walks up the tree until it finds a parent that is a different tag and then returns the item. For your example that would mean that if your  element was in a , ,  or whatever it would detect it as the root and return it.

Making a custom jquery selector with this should be possible too, but is obviously more complicated.

It should also be fairly easy to extend this to take an integer that defines the level. All you'd need to do is walk down the tree to the specified depth once you've found the root and return those elements.

Answer (score 0):

you could look into using the parent() and children() functions. is you need to go multiple levels , you can chain them like so.

```
$("#a01").parent().parent()  //returns <div id="0">
```

please see my comment, and I'll try to give a better solution.

Comment: thing is I wont know any ids, classes or node types, so I cant use a selector like '#a01'

Answer (score 0):

I get html fragment from ajax call, and I also need to get the root div from it. What I did was simply call `$(data)`, and jQuery will parse the returning text as HTML and give you the root.

```
$.ajax path,
  type: 'GET'
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  success: (data) ->
    $(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the top level parent of an element but still under the body, I'd go

```
$(obj).parents().filter('body > *')
```

Comment: but i wont know what the top node is it could be a snippet so cant use 'body'