# how can get attributes of root element?

Tags: jquery, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data columns="12" rows="0"/>
```

how can get attributes (rows) of root (data) element
in jquery?

i can with

```
var records = $(xml).find(":first").parent().attr("rows");
```

but not works :-/

thanks
Rob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it is a root node, use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

```
var records = $(xml).filter(":first").attr("rows");
```

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

jQuery's `.find()` selects by searching *inside* the root nodes, while `.filter()` selects from *among* the root nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var records = $(xml).find("data").attr("rows");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be working because it is having trouble finding the first element using the query you specified. This might be of some use to you:

[selecting root element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650063/selecting-root-element-in-jquery)

After that .attr("rows") should work.