# Strange jQuery error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

IE gives me an error here, where FireFox works just fine:

```
  $("#searched").text("");
  searched = $("messages > searched", xml).text();
```

The first line empties my < div >. The second line grabs a value out of my xml result. The error is specifically on the second line. It says the object doesn't support this property or method.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use empty() to empty an element.

Comment: The error is specifically on the second line. Sorry. Didn't fix it.

Comment: Your second line with the XML wont work. you need to pass in a jObject there. What exactly is XML, a string literal?

Comment: @Jason: jQuery places it into a jQuery object. It just gets flipped around into `$(xml).find("messages > searched")`

Comment: @patrick - ic, parsing XML, read this Michael - http://www.compoc.com/tuts/

Comment: Did you mean `#messages`, not `messages`?

Comment: @JasonJong: Not sure why you assumed that the variable `xml` is not a jQuery object. I usually use the convention `$xml` for jQuery objects, but not everybody does.

Comment: if search isn't previously declared, IE often complains. Make sure you do *var* searched = ...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen strange errors in IE when the Id of the element is the same as the variable, like this:

```
var my_id = document.getElementById('my_id');
```

Weird? Yes indeed, but I've seen it happening more than once.

Solution: rename your variable

Answer (score 0):

```
searched = $(xml).find("messages > searched").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is messages your root node? i.e. your xml structure is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messages>
  <searched>blah</searched>
  <searched>boo</searched>
</messages>
```

I am assuming your xml is a jquery object, i.e.

```
var xml = $("<?xml ...?><messages><searched>...</searched>...</messages>");
var searched = $("messages > searched", xml).text(); //this should assign blahbloo to searched.
```

In my experiments, when messages is the root node, you won't be able to do this, but if you change your xml input and wrap messages inside another root element, it works just fine on FF, Chrome and IE.

Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><foo><messages><searched>Searched Node 1</searched><searched>Searched Node 2</searched></messages></foo>";

      var xml = $(input);

      alert($("messages > searched", xml).text());

      $("messages > searched", xml).each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

So, either wrap your xml inside another root element or just bypass the messages and just do $("searched", xml)... which should work just fine.

Comment: Here is a link regarding root element and jquery... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291591/how-can-get-attributes-of-root-element