# How can I find a root div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, find, element, root

I use the jQuery function find() to extract a div of a html file. I use it in that way

```
data.find('#tpl_header')
```

Problem is jquery find() find only non root elements.
So this wont work:

```
[...]
<body>
   <div id="tpl_header" class="table header">
      <div class="tr">
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this way works:

```
[...]
<body>
   <div id="template"> <!-- because jQuery find function did not find root elements! -->

       <div id="tpl_header" class="table header">
          <div class="tr">
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to find this template div without adding a additional not really needed div?

[ADD]

The template reading function - already with the changes mention below by Sjoerd:

```
function LoadTemplate()
        {
            $.get('templates/' + template + '/main.html',  
                function(data) {
                    data = $(data);
                    $('#header').html($('#tpl_header', data));
            });
        }
```

Comment: I suppose, you have the content of BODY in your "data" ?

Comment: The `find` is more for things like `$("#tpl_header").find(".tr")` this for example will find the child element with `tr` class inside the header element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thread gives me a working solution. I have to use the .filter() function to get the root div.

Source: [how can get attributes of root element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291591/how-can-get-attributes-of-root-element)

Answer (score 5):

```
var templateElement = $('#tpl_header')
```

`element.find()` only finds descendants of that element, whereas `$()` finds elements on the whole page.

Comment: Sounds logical but did not work for my function. I add the template reading function in the initial post.