# jQuery: How to find out the root tag name in XML?

Tags: jquery, xml

I need to know the name of the root tag in XML. How do I find it out?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291591/how-can-get-attributes-of-root-element

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (*safe*) way to grab it (assuming you have the XML in a string or jQuery wrapper already) would be:

```
var firstNodeName = $(xml).attr("nodeName");
```

If your XML is already in a wrapper, no need for the `$()`, just `xml.attr()` will do.

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PHNBe/1/).

Comment: No need for `.first()` at all - `attr` only returns the first element's attribute value.

Comment: @Alnitak - I had this in for older version safety...but indeed you're right, even 1.4 and back handles that fine with xml as well, good call and thanks - updated.

Comment: FWIW, Darin's `.nodeName` on the 0th element is of course a lot faster than using `.attr()`.

Comment: @Alnitak - yes, but it's not *safe*, if the XML failed to load for any reason (you're almost always dealing with an AJAX situation when dealing with XML selectors) it would blow up...hence the "safe" part in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*:eq(0)');
```

Would select the first element in the complete tree.