# What is reliable way to find XML root element name using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I tried using [jQuery parse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) but, it is helpful only when searching by a value or when element name is known in advance.

I need to obtain `root element` name itself from the document. How do I achieve this?
I can do string arithmetic to get this out, but it would not be reliable approach in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure JavaScript solution for your problem (I hope).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLjw7/)

```
// The initial string
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><myRoot><someNode></someNode></myRoot>';

// Parse the string with the function defined below
var doc = parseXml(xmlString);

// Extract the name of the root element
var rootName = doc.documentElement.nodeName;

alert(rootName); // Alerts "myRoot" in this example

// Cross-browser function to parse an XML string
function parseXml(xmlString) {
    var doc;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // Internet Explorer
        doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.loadXML(xmlString);
    } else {
        // Other browsers
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check this example

```
var xml = '<xml><thing>stuff</thing><thing2>value</thing2></xml>';
var firstNodeName = $(xml).attr("nodeName");
alert("The first node name is: " + firstNodeName );
```

it return "XML"

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PHNBe/1/)

Comment: For string, it worked fine, but for xml document like below.. code does not work var `xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><xml><thing>stuff</thing><thing2>value</thing2></xml>";`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291591/how-can-get-attributes-of-root-element