# On clicking the anchor tag the outermost div must hide along with its child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag, which contains a div tag, which contains a ul tag which then contains many li tags. On of these li tags contains an anchor element, which when clicked causes the outermost div to hide.

for example

```
<div class="object" id="123">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="hide">hide outermost div and its child elements</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="object" id="124">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="hide">hide outermost div and its child elements</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

on clicking the anchor tag the outermost div must hide along with its child elements.

I reckon i need to use parentNode repeatedly.. but is there a simpler way to directly access the outer most div and hence its id. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What designates an "outermost `<div>`"? You could theoretically follow the chain of `<div>` elements to the container, which I'm sure is not your goal.

Comment: I don't think that linked question really covers directly what this question asked. Yes, it's supporting information, but if that were the standard then 2/3 of the questions here should be closed.

Comment: What is the question being asked?

Comment: thanks for ur comments friends..
@wex -- what designates the outermost  div is the class "object"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650063/selecting-root-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is fairly unclear. It *almost* sounds like you are looking for a generic way of accessing the "outer div". If that is the case, it doesn't make sense that you have ids on both your anchor and your outer div. If there's only ever going to be one "outer div" and one anchor to hide it, all you need is:

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('#123').hide();
});
```

If you want a generic way of doing this, you should add classes to both:

```
<div class="outerDiv" id="123">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hider" id="hide">hide outermost div and its child elements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and:

```
$('.hider').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.outerDiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .. i have modified my question so that the my query is conveyed properly..so when i click #hide the parent div containing class "object" must get hidden..

Comment: @Bhoot OK that makes a little more sense. You should also add a class to the #hide thing. You don't want to have more than one element in a document with the same ID. See my updated answer.